# Hiding/Virtual Function Usage C++

Tags: c++, class, function, virtual

This is kind of a specific question that I had not been able to find a solution to for quite a while. I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Mammal
{
  public:
  Mammal() {cout << "Mammal Constructor\n";}
  virtual ~Mammal() {cout << "Mammal Destructor\n";}
  virtual void Run() {cout << "Mammal Ran One Space\n";}

  protected:
  int mammalDistance;
};

class Horse : public Mammal
{
    public:
    Horse() {cout << "Horse Constructor\n";}
    ~Horse() {cout << "Horse Destructor\n";}
    void Run() {cout << "Horse Ran One Space\n";}
    void Run(int distance) {horseDistance = distance;
                            cout << "Horse Ran " << horseDistance << " Spaces\n";}

    protected:
    int horseDistance;
};

int main()
{
    Mammal *pHorse = new Horse;
    pHorse->Run(5);
    delete pHorse;
    return 0;
}
```

Now this code works if I take the void Run(int horseDistance) and move it up into Mammal but I wanted to know if there was a way to keep it in horse without it remaining hidden.

Edit: I mean it compiles and works as intended if I take the function that accepts input and move it up into Mammal instead of having it within the Horse class like it is currently.
Yes I would like it if it could change the value of horseDistance when it is being passed in.
Edit: O I get what your saying. I edited the code.

Comment: Can you explain further, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Define "works". Do you mean "compiles"?

Comment: do you still want `run(int)` to reference `horseDistance`?  and if so, did you intend for the parameter `horseDistance` or the member `Horse::horseDistance`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.  One is to keep track of the fact that your pointer is a horse:

```
int main()
{
    Horse *pHorse = new Horse;
    pHorse->Run(5);
    delete pHorse;
    return 0;
}
```

The other is to declare a virtual function in `Mammal`:

```
virtual void Run(int mammalDistance) = 0;
```

I'd pick option #1 if horses were the only things running specific distances, option #2 otherwise.

Comment: You could even add a default implementation: `void Run(int d) { for(int x = 0; x < d; ++x) Run(); }`. But that's up to the OP to consider.

Comment: Chose this answer because it allowed me to keep the member function in Horse and helped me understand the most why I wasnt able to do what I had originally wanted. Other answers were all possible solutions though.

Answer (score 1):

```
Mammal *pHorse = new Horse;
pHorse->Run(5);
```

Doesn't work because there is no member function in Mammal with the signature `void Run(int)`. More precise: the function `void Run(int)` given in the Horse class is not an override for the function `void Run()` in Mammal, because of the different signatures.

You should consider adding `void Run(int)` to the Mammal interface, if it is a function more subclasses will implement.

Answer (score 0):

Now you know that pHorse is a Horse, but for the compiler, it is different.
The only way to do it is to check with dynamic cast if pHorse is a horse and then cast it to a Horse* and cast the method Run(5).

```
Horse* pHorse2=dynamic_cast<Horse*>(pHorse);
if(pHorse2!=NULL){
   pHorse2->Run(5);
}else{
   pHorse->Run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for polymorphism here.  All your derived `Mammals` simply have to implement `getDistance()` and `setDistance()` and also can implement `getAnimal()` to provide a name.  I think there's still some room for improvement on the design, but you'll be getting the hang of polymorphism this way.  Something like this perhaps:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Mammal
{
public:
  Mammal() {cout << "Mammal Constructor\n";}
  virtual ~Mammal() {cout << "Mammal Destructor\n";}
  virtual void Run() {cout << getAnimal() << " Ran " << getDistance() << " Space\n";}
  virtual void Run(int p_distance)
  {setDistance(p_distance);
    cout << getAnimal() << " Ran " << getDistance() << " Spaces\n";}

protected:
  virtual void setDistance(int p_distance) {mammalDistance = p_distance;}
  virtual int getDistance() {return mammalDistance;}
  virtual string getAnimal() {return "Mammal";}
  int mammalDistance;
};

class Horse : public Mammal
{
public:
    Horse() {cout << "Horse Constructor\n";}
    ~Horse() {cout << "Horse Destructor\n";}
protected:
    int horseDistance;
    virtual string getAnimal() {return "Horse";}
};

int main()
{
    Mammal *pHorse = new Horse;
    pHorse->Run(5);
    delete pHorse;
    return 0;
}
```